# Two sites, same codebase mystery

Tags: configuration

Ubunutu Server, two Drupal sites. One dev and one live. Both domain names take you to the same code and database, the ones correct for the live site. 
Checked apache virtual host files. Both the dev and live sites are pointing to different directories where they should go, one to the live code, and one to dev.

What setting, and where, could make the dev site point to the live one, instead of where apache's virtual host file says it's pointing?

*I should add, this occurred after a server upgrade.

Comment: If it's multilingual, and you've set a language domain, it will redirect. Otherwise you can look in .htaccess for redirects, or check if you've got the redirect module enabled, and that module is redirecting it.

Comment: thank you Jaypan! I have checked the htaccess, but will check now for the redirect module. Your reputation on drupal.org proceeds you, you are famous for answering questions. :)

Comment: I deleted the htaccess file in the dev site directory to see if any of the rewrite rules were even being followed. The site is still up with it deleted, so the server is pointing the dev domain to the live site directory. :( I inherited this site and I'm trying to figure it out. Should the /etc/apach2/apache2.conf file have ServerName [live site domain] at the very top? That seems strange to me. Also should that file have "AllowOverride None" under the <Directory>? AllowOverride All is set in the virtual hosts files.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this was that the dev site was being redirected to the live site, where the "https" was then crossed out, but the domain name remains, confusingly, the same.